# How to remove the 5 second boot delay on Digispark PRO (Attiny167)

Tags: attiny85, digispark

I know there’s already a solution for removing the 5 seconds boot delay on Digispark (Attiny85), by writing a new bootloader someone already did to the Digispark. And to write code to it, you need to ground one pin.

This delay exists so the Attiny85, when powered on, waits for USB programming. Only after 5 seconds it will run the code written to it..

But I can’t find information on how to remove this 5 second delay on the Attiny167 - Digispark PRO.

Could the same modified bootloader of the Attiny85 be burned on the 167?

Or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't see the delay in the [code](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus), only in the command line util. What bootloader are you using?

Comment: @DaveNewton I’m using the stock bootloader. The firmware of the Digispark Pro is 2.2. Everytime it powers on the internal led flashes for 5-6 seconds and only then any code written to it is executed. I’d like to power up the Digispark PRO and any code be executed imediatelly. Every Digispark PRO behaves this way, as far as I know. I don’t know if the correct name is delay, but when powered on, the board waits for this 5 seconds to check if any code is about to be written through the USB port. If not, it executes de code that was already uploaded to it.